# Converting nested LinearLayouts to RelativeLayout - layout-above is ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

So I've completed an early version of my Android app and begun testing on various devices.  I'm finding my nested LinearLayouts aren't sufficient for my purposes so I'm trying to convert the nested LinearLayouts to a RelativeLayout.  Below is my starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundhomescreen"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_txt_Username"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@layout/textboxlogin"
                android:hint="Username or Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textColorHint="#ddd" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_txt_Password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@layout/textboxlogin"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColorHint="#ddd" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_btn_submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SIGN IN"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:background="@layout/buttonsigninbackground" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_txt_or"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="- or -"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_btn_navCreateAccount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/buttoncreateaccountbackground"
                android:text="CREATE AN ACCOUNT"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is where I've gotten so far but with some issues - even after following this tutorial - [Visual Guide to RelativeLayout](http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=334)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:context=".LoginActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundhomescreen"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_txt_Username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@layout/textboxlogin"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#ddd" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_txt_Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@layout/textboxlogin"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#ddd"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_txt_Username"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:background="@layout/buttonsigninbackground" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_txt_or"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="- or -"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_btn_navCreateAccount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:id="@id/login_btn_navCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@layout/buttoncreateaccountbackground"
        android:text="CREATE AN ACCOUNT"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ultimately I need a relative layout that's bottom aligned so I can place other views just above the previous.  In my second code sample above, textview 'login_txt_or' that references login_btn_navCreateAccount seems to be ignored.

Any clue to why this is?  If it's of any use, I'm using Xamarin.Android 4.10.1 in Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_login_relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundgameplaying"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_tv_error"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textColor="#f00" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_txt_Username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@layout/textboxlogin"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#ddd"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_tv_error" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_txt_Password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@layout/textboxlogin"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#ddd"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_txt_Username" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_txt_Password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:background="@layout/buttonsigninbackground"
        android:text="SIGN IN" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginTxtOr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_btn_submit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:text="- or -" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_navCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginTxtOr"
        android:background="@layout/buttoncreateaccountbackground"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:text="CREATE AN ACCOUNT" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```